# How do I return a list of column values when the rows are the same for every other column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I apologize if my question was unclear. I have a dataframe that contains these values:

| Rating | UserName | ReviewDate | Article | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Madison | 2023-06-05 | 025-03-7579 | 0.924742 |
| 5 | Madison | 2023-06-05 | 025-03-2888 | 0.924742 |
| 5 | Lindsanna | 2023-06-05 | 025-03-9268 | 0.990300 |
| 4 | Mamax4 | 2023-06-05 | 025-03-1736 | 0.875178 |

As we can see, the first two rows contain the same data except for the 'Article' column. I want to write a code a that returns me a list/tuple that contains all the values of the 'Article' field that contain the same data. In this particular case the ideal output would be something like:

```
[('025-03-7579','025-03-2888')]
```

I have tried to use `df.groupby('Article')` to create two lists and compare them, returning a tuple whenever there was a match in articles but I have had no success.

Any feedback would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by all columns except `Article` and filter groups with duplicate values:

```
[tuple(gr['Article']) for _, gr in df.groupby(['Rating', 'UserName', 'ReviewDate', 'Score']) 
 if gr.index.size > 1]
```

---

```
[('025-03-7579', '025-03-2888')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a `groupby` more similar to something like this

```
df1 =  df.groupby(["Rating","UserName","ReviewDate","Score"])["Article"].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df['Article'][df.duplicated(
    df.columns[df.columns != 'Article'], keep=False)].to_list()
```

Output:

```
['025-03-7579', '025-03-2888']
```

---

If a tuple per group is needed:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns != 'Article']
(df[df.duplicated(cols, keep=False)]
 .groupby(cols.to_list())['Article'].agg(tuple).tolist())
```

Output:

```
[('025-03-7579', '025-03-2888')]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what 'cols' is supposed to mean since it is not defined. I thought it might have meant to say 'columns' but after trying the code it simply returns me an empty tuple

Comment: `cols` contains the names of the columns of `df`, except column `Article`, @FarazKhan.